# Suppress OpenCV Output Message in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I use OpenCV [`selectROIs()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga0f11fad74a6432b8055fb21621a0f893) command. It gives below output message for each ROI selection.

> Finish the selection process by pressing ESC button!
> Select a ROI and then press SPACE or ENTER button!
> Cancel the selection process by pressing c button!

I tried below code to suppress output of `selectROIs()`

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys
import os

@contextmanager
def suppress_stdout():
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = devnull
        try:  
            yield
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout

with suppress_stdout():
    ROIs = cv.selectROIs("Select ROI", img)
```

This method didn't work. I changed all `out` as `err` but it didn't work as well. How can suppress it?

Comment: did it suppress a regular print instead of the selectROI?

Comment: you could ask OpenCV to give that function an argument saying whether to print those messages or not. to do that, open an issue on OpenCV's github.

Comment: it's not enough to rebind `sys.stdout`. you have to touch the process's file handle for stdout. OpenCV doesn't care about what `sys.stdout` is set to. it uses the process's stdout handle.

Comment: [`modules/highgui/src/roiSelector.cpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/highgui/src/roiSelector.cpp)